# Sending both text and image on WhatsApp in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have to complete a project from my college. Under this project, an app is to be developed which has the ability to send both text and image simultaneously as a WhatsApp message. I can only send text as a message on Whats App with the help of the given code, but if I want to send both the image and text to someone, I do not have the information.
I use following code for send Text message through whats app. Text message has send but i want to send both Image and Text combine through Whats app. How can i do?

```
    String phoneNumberWithCountryCode = "+5200000000";
    String message = "This is testing Message";

    startActivity(
     new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(
        String.format("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%s&text=%s", phoneNumberWithCountryCode, message)
    )
   )
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do some practice first to learn. Anyway Use the given code to send data and image together on Whats App. Use an image box, edit text box, file location, etc. to use the code.

```
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) 
    imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        shareImageandText(bitmap);
    }
});
    }
    private void shareImageandText(Bitmap bitmap) {
Uri uri = getmageToShare(bitmap);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// putting uri of image to be shared
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

// adding text to share
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s5.getText().toString());

// setting type to image
intent.setType("image/png");

// calling startactivity() to share
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
   }

    private Uri getmageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
File imagefolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
Uri uri = null;
try {
    imagefolder.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(imagefolder, "shared_image.png");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, 
    "com.niky.sample.fileprovider", file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return uri;
    }
```

Comment: Do not make the work of other users, if you do not see any effort to solve it by himself

Comment: We do not do any other user's work here but help each other to learn knowledge. Especially when it comes to completing a college project, you may not have noticed that I have advised him earlier to try and complete the work on your own before asking anyone for help. Repeated effort makes man perfect.

Comment: Thanks sir, with the help of your given code I have solved my problem, thanks